# error handling with .post()

Tags: jquery

I have to modify a project written by someone else. Because the code is a mess I can't really change this $.post() (or replace it by $.ajax()). What I need to do, is to know if the post returns something else then JSON and return it.

```
$.post('balbal.html', json, function(data) { ... my coude ... }, 'json')
```

I can see the post response in the console.log. Is there a simple way to retrieve it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's a couple of ways to do it, but if you're not getting the error response available through the returned JSON data object, you can use [$.ajaxSetup()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/) to define defaults for *all* ajax calls through jQuery.  Even though the `$.post()` method doesn't specify an error handler or callback in and of itself, the `$.ajaxSetup()` method will capture any ajax faults and execute the function you define for it.

Alternatively, there is also an [$.ajaxError()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/) function that will do the same sort of thing.

Note that this will not work if your JSON response is returned correctly but with a server-side error code.  If you want to capture these sorts of cases, you might be best to look for them using the [$.ajaxComplete()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/) method

Answer (score 156):

Define the error callback immediately after the post. Note the semi-colon placement only at the end.

```
$.post('balbal.html', json, function(data) {
    // ... my code ...
})
.fail(function(response) {
    alert('Error: ' + response.responseText);
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/deferred.fail/

**For older versions of jQuery (pre-1.8)** Use [.error](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) instead with the same syntax.

Comment: Would be nice to get the actual error message, but this is cool thanx

Comment: @John and anyone coming here in the future, if you do .fail(res) you can then do res.responseText to access the error message.

Comment: now, you can do res.responseText  or res.responseJSON for the error message and json object

Comment: just print the response object during .fail() in console.  console.log(response); you can see all the available objects you can probably make use of.

Comment: You can get the status by `response.statusText` and the options are: `notmodified`, `nocontent`, `erro`, `timeout`, `abort`, or `parsererror`

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

```js
// Assign handlers immediately after making the request, and remember the jqxhr object for this request.
var jqxhr = $.post("example.php", function() {
  alert("success");
  })
  .done(function() {
    alert("second success");
  })
  .fail(function() {
    alert("error");
  })
  .always(function() {
    alert("finished");
  });
});
 
// Your other code here.
 
// Set another completion function for the request above.
jqxhr.always(function() {
  alert( "second finished" );
});
```

**$.post Documentation**: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Answer (score 2):

You can use `$.ajax()` (`$.post` is a shortcut that ends up calling it anyway), and define the error callback.

Or, if you really do not want to do that, call

```
$.ajaxError(function(){
   //error handler
})
```

before that `$.post`

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ There is no error handling in `$.post` because it is just a shortcut method to save typing.

Comment: i tried the ajaxError but it seams not to execute. I get a answer form the post but its, a php error and not  the json i expect.

Comment: Then hijack the success handler and add a check there first. Something will get called, no? :P

Comment: it seams not to enter the success handler if the response is not json.