# Ajax Failure Response in Contact Form

Tags: php, ajax, forms

I've gotten my contact form to display the success message and the loading bar upon submitting, but for some reason, the failure message will not display. It just continues to show the loading bar.

I tried using both of the below, and they didn't do the trick. The failure message should display if required fields aren't filled or e-mail is invalid. Any help is much appreciated.

What I tried:

```
   else if(response == 'failure'){
statusdiv.html('<p class="ajax-success" >Please sure all required information is entered and try again.</p>');
}

 else {
statusdiv.html('<p class="ajax-success" >Please sure all required information is entered and try again.</p>');
}
```

Full Code:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" >
function cvf_form_validate(element) {
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(element).offset().top-100}, 150);
    element.effect("highlight", { color: "#F2DEDE" }, 1500);
    element.effect('shake');
}

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
var placeholder=$('#status-placeholder');
jQuery('<div id="comment-status"></div>').insertBefore(placeholder);
var statusdiv=$('#comment-status');

    $('body').on('click', '.submit', function() {
       statusdiv.html('<div class="wrap go"><div class="loader bar"><div class="sfmgreen"></div><div class="dkblue"></div><div class="ltblue"></div><div class="aqua"></div></div>');

        if($('.input-name').val() === '') {
            cvf_form_validate($('.input-name'));

        } else if($('.input-email').val() === '') {            
            cvf_form_validate($('.input-email'));

        } else if($('.input-message').val() === '') {              
            cvf_form_validate($('.input-message'));

        } else {
            var data = {
                'action': 'cvf_send_message',
                'name': $('.input-name').val(),
                'email': $('.input-email').val(),
                'message': $('.input-message').val()
            };

            var ajaxurl = '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>';
            $.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
                if(response === 'success'){
                    statusdiv.html('<p class="ajax-success" >Thanks! Your message has been sent successfully.</p>');
                    $('.input-name').val(''); $('.input-email').val(''); $('.input-message').val('');
                }
                else if(response == 'failure'){
statusdiv.html('<p class="ajax-success" >Please sure all required information is entered and try again.</p>');
}
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Are you receiving string literals from the server you're requesting? In this case you should check `response.data`. It is easy to debug such kind of things on your own. Or would you like just to check the status of response? `response.status`

Comment: I'm pretty new to this, so I'm going to try and guess. Does that mean I should use this:

`else if(response == 'failure'){
statusdiv.html('<p class="ajax-success" >Please sure all required information is entered and try again.</p>');
response.status;
}`

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697719/error-handling-with-post)

Comment: Ok, thanks. I read through that. It looks like `$.post` should be replaced with `$.ajax` in order to handle the error callback. I tried that with no success. I also tried to add `$.ajaxError(function(){...]` before `$.post` and `.error(function() {... });` after it, as described in that thread. Neither seemed to work. Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: No, I am not a fortune teller to guess what may be wrong. Post your code (jsfiddle) and we can sort it out. First of all you need to make sure you get the terms the same way all do. An error is a state that either webserver returns or when server is unreachable, for example. If you have a special state in your app's logic, it is not an error in terms of ajax request. You just return a property in your response by which you can distinguish there is smth wrong with request

Comment: Besides, if  you're using jquery version higher than 1.8 you should use `.fail()` instead of `.error()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks so much for your help and patience! I was able to figure it out.

Instead of adding the error callback after the success handler, I needed to add it after each input. This allows the error to define which fields are missing and specify for the user what to do.

```
if($('.input-name').val() === '') {
    statusdiv.html('<p class="ajax-error" >Please fill out your name and try again.</p>'); response.status;

} else if($('.input-email').val() === '') {            
    statusdiv.html('<p class="ajax-error" >Please fill out your e-mail and try again.</p>'); response.status;

} else if($('.input-message').val() === '') {              
    statusdiv.html('<p class="ajax-error" >Please add a message and try again.</p>'); response.status;

}
```